# React : Click event is not propagating if we click on dynamically created children by iterating in a map

Tags: reactjs, key, jsx

```
const items = ["success", "2h ago"];
        var outputElements = [];
        items.map((item, index) => {
            outputElements.push(<div key={"object-instance-id-c28c4dc9-77e3-4a07-95bc-3bf7685a1239"
            }> item </div>);
        })
```

Key is **object-instance-id-c28c4dc9-77e3-4a07-95bc-3bf7685a1239** generated dynamically.

If we click on outputElement the event is not propogating.

**Is there any max length for keys in react?**

Comment: Where are you setting the `click` event?

Comment: It seems that you're binding click event before the creation of element. However, share complete code.

Comment: I can't put all the code here but the click event is attached to the parent somewhere, <div class="parent" onclick="myFunction()"><div>Header</div>{this._getChildElements()}</div>.  The function _getChildElements will have the logic to generate the childs. If we click on div containing 'Header' text the event is propogating.